# Join multiple CSV files by using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, join

I am trying to create a CSV file from multiple csv files by using python pandas.

`accreditation.csv` :-

```
"pid","accreditation_body","score"
"25799","TAAC","4.5"
"25796","TAAC","5.6"
"25798","DAAC","5.7"
```

`ref_university`  :-

```
"id","pid","survery_year","end_year"
"1","25799","2018","2018"
"2","25797","2016","2018"
```

I want to create a new table by reading the instruction from `table_structure.csv`. I want to join two tables and rewrite the `accreditation.csv` . `REFERENCES ref_university(id, survey_year)` is connecting with `ref_university.csv` and inserting `id` and `survery_year` columns value by matching the `pid` column value.

`table_structure.csv` :-

```
table_name,attribute_name,attribute_type,Description
,,,
accreditation,accreditation_body,varchar,
,grading,varchar,
,pid,int4, "REFERENCES ref_university(id, survey_year)"
,score,float8,
```

Modified CSV file should look like,

New `accreditation.csv` :-

```
"accreditation_body","grading","pid","id","survery_year","score"
"TAAC","","25799","1","2018","2018","4.5"
"TAAC","","25797","2","2016","2018","5.6"
"DAAC","","25798","","","","5.7"
```

I can read the csv in panda

```
df = pd.read_csv("accreditation.csv")
```

But, what is the recommended way to read the REFERENCES instruction and pick the columns value. If there is no value then column should be blank.
We can not hardcore `pid` in panda function. We have to read `table_structure.csv` and match if there is a Reference then call the mentioned columns. It should not be merged, just the specific columns should be added.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic solution is possible, but not so easy:

```
df = pd.read_csv("table_structure.csv")

#remove only NaNs rows
df = df.dropna(how='all')
#repalce NaNs by forward filling
df['table_name'] = df['table_name'].ffill()

#create for each table_name one row
df = (df.dropna(subset=['Description'])
       .join(df.groupby('table_name')['attribute_name'].apply(list)
              .rename('cols'), 'table_name'))

#get name of DataFrame and new columns names
df['df1'] = df['Description'].str.extract('REFERENCES\s*(.*)\s*\(')
df['new_cols'] = df['Description'].str.extract('\(\s*(.*)\s*\)')
df['new_cols'] = df['new_cols'].str.split(', ')
#remove unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(['attribute_type','Description'], axis=1).set_index('table_name')
print (df)
table_name                                                                
accreditation            pid  [accreditation_body, grading, pid, score]   

                          df1           new_cols  
table_name                                        
accreditation  ref_university  [id, survey_year]  

#for select by named create dictioanry of DataFrames
data = {'accreditation' : pd.read_csv("accreditation.csv"), 
        'ref_university': pd.read_csv("ref_university.csv")}
```

---

```
#seelct by index
v = df.loc['accreditation']
print (v)
attribute_name                                          pid
cols              [accreditation_body, grading, pid, score]
df1                                          ref_university
new_cols                                  [id, survey_year]
Name: accreditation, dtype: object
```

Select by dictionary and by `Series` v

```
df = pd.merge(data[v.name], 
               data[v['df1']][v['new_cols'] + [v['attribute_name']]], 
               on=v['attribute_name'], 
               how='left')
```

is converted to:

```
df = pd.merge(data['accreditation'], 
               data['ref_university'][['id', 'survey_year'] + ['pid']], 
               on='pid', 
               how='left')
```

and return:

```
print (df)
     pid accreditation_body  score   id  survey_year
0  25799               TAAC    4.5  1.0       2018.0
1  25796               TAAC    5.6  NaN          NaN
2  25798               DAAC    5.7  NaN          NaN
```

Last add new columns by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.union(v['cols']))
print (df)
  accreditation_body  grading   id    pid  score  survey_year
0               TAAC      NaN  1.0  25799    4.5       2018.0
1               TAAC      NaN  NaN  25796    5.6          NaN
2               DAAC      NaN  NaN  25798    5.7          NaN
```

Comment: I can not hardcore pid. We have to read table_structure.csv and match if there is a reference then call that columns.

Comment: Also, in the new accreditation.csv , there is a new column grading. Value should be blank in this column

Comment: @DineshAhuja - added solution for dynamically merge.

Comment: It looks good. But, I have multiple csv files and there are multiple rows in table_structure.csv also. If there is a "REFERENCES something" , then it should input "something.csv" automatically and we can not use use column names manually, because it is a big file with multiple columns.

Comment: @DineshAhuja - really hard create general solution... This solution is only for 2 DataFrames. But if add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there is it possible. Also add all possible combination in `Description`, but again, relly hard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Try it! When files are huge set low_memory=False in pd.read_csv()

```html
import pandas as pd
import glob

# gets path to the folder datafolder
path = r"C:\Users\data_folder"

# reads all files with.csv ext

filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.csv")
print('File names:', filenames)
df=pd.DataFrame()
# for loop to iterate and concat csv files
for file in filenames:
    temp=pd.read_csv(file,low_memory=False)
    df= pd.concat([df, temp], axis=1) #set axis =0 if you want to join rows
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```